# Pollyfiller shows wrong date format in internet explorer

Tags: asp.net, culture, polyfills

I have the following scenario:

my pc was installed with an English version of windows most likely US culture.

Now I've already changed the culture settings for date-time formatting on my pc to preferences to d/MM/yyyy.

I have an English version of internet explorer installed and a dutch version of chrome installed.

Now when i run the demo of the pollyfiller found [here](https://github.com/jonstipe/date-polyfill) I get the following results:

running it in my Dutch version of chrome the date time picker turns out to be in dutch and the date format is correctly following the dutch format: dd/MM/yyyy

running it in my English version of Internet Explorer the date time picker turns out to be in english and the date format is incorrectly following the format: MM/dd/yyyy

in my asp page i have tried putting: `UICulture="nl" Culture="nl-BE"`
but this has no effect.

how can i make this pollyfiller date picker look at my culture correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all we had to do was add this piece of code into the page and it was fixed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.webshims.activeLang('nl');
</script>
```